# ListAdapter change items position after submitlist

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter, notifydatasetchanged

After `listAdapter` load to recyclerview, some data change on items. I use `submitList` method to reload list. It updates list well but when do `submitList` it change position of items. For example: The upper one goes down. Lower one goes up. I can't find notify list without this movement.

CartFragment.kt

```
viewModel.increaseCart.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
    it?.onLoading {  }
    it?.onSuccess {
        it?.data?.let { cart->
            initTotalFee(cart)
            adapter?.submitList(cart.cartItems)
        }
    }
    it?.onError { e->
        e
    }
}
```

How to change list without submitList method?

Just tried these.

```
adapter?.submitList(cart.cartItems)
adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Consider sorting the list passed to `subimtList` to ensure the stable order of the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what `cartItems` are but i assume that they are objects. If that object has a field of `price` or something comperable, than you can sort it and send to adapter. With this approach it will not randomized in adapter:

```
viewModel.increaseCart.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
    it?.onLoading {  }
    it?.onSuccess {
        it?.data?.let { cart->
            initTotalFee(cart)
            val sortedList = cart.cartItems.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.price }))
            adapter?.submitList(sortedList)
        }
    }
    it?.onError { e->
        e
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it has. but it will change list position again according to price. I do this method when user increase quantity of item. I use notifyChanged now. It seem work.

Comment: To be precise, you can add a field called `addedDate` to the cardItems, and compare them, it will not confuse again. `addedDate` can be real time or just Int value like 0 or 1.

Comment: I can't find another wat and I did what you wrote.